# Singletons using structs in C#

Tags: c#, .net, struct, autoboxing

This isn't really an optimization question or anything. It's essentially a what-the-heck-is-going-on-here kind of question. The singleton pattern is used to have a single instance of an object used multiple times. That's all well and good, but if I try to do a similar pattern with a struct, it don't get a single instance.

I came about this trying to do something with the `Color` struct in `System.Drawing`. Here is some example code:

```
    class Colors
    {
        private static Color _red;
        public static Color Red
        {
            get
            {
                if (_red.IsEmpty)
                    _red = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0x42, 0x39);

                return _red;
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var redOne = Colors.Red;
        var redTwo = Colors.Red;

        Console.WriteLine("redOne.Equals(redTwo) : {0}", redOne.Equals(redTwo));
        Console.WriteLine("redOne == redTwo : {0}", redOne == redTwo);
        Console.WriteLine("Object.Equals(redOne, redTwo) : {0}", Object.Equals(redOne, redTwo));
        Console.WriteLine("Object.ReferenceEquals(redOne, redTwo) : {0}", Object.ReferenceEquals(redOne, redTwo));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

The output for this is:

```
redOne.Equals(redTwo) : True
redone == redTwo : True
Object.Equals(redOne, redTwo) : True
Object.ReferenceEquals(redOne, redTwo) : False
```

The first three results are to be expected, but the last is what surprised me. Now, my best guess is that when `_red` is returned from `Colors.Red` it's returning a copy, as normal value types do. So, while there is only a single instance of `_red`, `Colors.Red` returns a brand new instance, and that is what gets stored into redOne and redTwo. Is my thinking correct?

Also, if that **is** correct, is there any point in using the `static` keyword on structs?

Thanks

Comment: `is there any point in using the static keyword on structs?` -- In the context of your code, `static` essentially means that the color red is *the same color for all instances of the Color class.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ReferenceEquals will not work with a struct/value type, only a class.

Calling ReferenceEquals on two structs will 'box' each struct into it's own memory location and then compare the two (obviously) different addresses.

Since a class is already a reference type, the call to ReferenceEquals compares the actual address of the instance.

Essentially you do not need to store a static copy of 'Red'.  Change the code to the following:

```
class Colors
{
    public static Color Red
    {
        get
        {
            return Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0x42, 0x39);
        }
    }
}
```

Additional reading:
[MSDN - Structs (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saxz13w4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I had done exactly that at first, then noticed it wasn't returning a single instance. That lead to expanding it, hoping for a different outcome. Glad to know there is no difference.

Answer (score 6):

> So, while there is only a single instance of _red, Colors.Red returns a brand new instance, and that is what gets stored into redOne and redTwo. Is my thinking correct?

Yes.  You have two copies, since Color is a value type.  When you use `ReferenceEquals`, you box the struct into an `object`, and call `Object.ReferenceEquals` on the two (distinctly different) boxed objects.

> Also, if that is correct, is there any point in using the static keyword on structs?

The main point here isn't to make this a singleton - it's to simplify the API so you have what is effectively a constant value for a color: `Colors.Red` or `Colors.Green`.  Without this being static, you would need to manually create a "red" color each time.  The properties in this case are effectively a nicer looking factory method on the `Colors` class.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `_red` will hold a single instance of `Color` that gets initialized once.  Because .net does not provide any way to return a reference to a struct instance, however, every call to property `Red` will return a new struct instance whose fields, public and private, are initialized with values copied from `_red`.  Further, because value type fields do not store objects, but merely data which can be implicitly copied to heap objects as needed (every value type has a corresponding heap object type; both are described by the same `Type` object, but they are not the same type), every time a value type is converted to a heap type (such as `Object`), a new heap object instance is created with field values initialized from the value-type instance.